# in jsp by using JSTL , how i can get inserted id

Tags: jsp, jstl

in PHP when i execute  query i can get id for this query by call mysql_insert_id() function

how i can get inserted ID for my query

assuming i have this table

```
 ID    NAME
-------------
  1    jack
  2    sara
```

```
<sql:update dataSource="${snapshot}" var="result">
    INSERT INTO users (NAME) VALUES (?);
      <sql:param value="${name}" />
</sql:update>
```

if i execute this query, i expect to get ID number 3.
but how i can get it?

Comment: what is your database vendor?

Comment: Unrelated, but this is just example, prototype code, right?

Comment: @dave-newton yes , just i want to  know how i can get inserted id for current query

Comment: Use the SQL, I guess?

Answer (score 0):

You can use update and query enclosed in sql:transaction tag:

```
<sql:transaction dataSource="${snapshot}"  >
  <sql:update  var="result">
    INSERT INTO users (NAME) VALUES (?);
      <sql:param value="${name}" />
  </sql:update>
  <sql:query var="nextIdTable" >
    SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID() as lastId
  </sql:query >
</sql:transaction>
Value is : ${ nextIdTable.rows[0].lastId }.
```